# Objective-C: CDATA editing or converting

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

obj-c question. I have text that I parse that contains CDDATA (html amp chars etc). Now, is there a way to render it on the UI with some control, locally, and secondly, is there a clean way of editing it (converting it perhaps from cddata to text in a textarea)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for sure the data is `CDATA`, you can wrap it in a tag and use `NSXMLParser` to parse the into an `NSString*`